# Unable to configure endpoints

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, restful-authentication

I am working on a project where one team created wcf service and we MVC team has to consume that service and passing parameters to that service. On going with different ways of calling the service we are unable to call that service because of the following errors:

1. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:1295
2. No endpoint configured
3. Endpoint is not listening
4. Could not find endpoint "" and contract in service model client configuration.
5. Remote server returning 500 (Internal error)

Please help

```
   [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITnTService
    {

        [OperationContract]      
        List<GetCity_Result> Getcity();

        [OperationContract]
        bool PContact(Person item);
}
```

Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
      <service name="TnT.Services.TnTService">
        <endpoint address="basic1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TnT.Services.ITnTService"/>
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
 <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TnTEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TnT_Model.csdl|res://*/TnT_Model.ssdl|res://*/TnT_Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=183.82.48.194;initial catalog=TnT;persist security info=True;user id=dev;password=dev;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please: 1) Share service contract. 2) web config

Comment: Is the port open? If you put the complete URL for the service in a browser window, you should get a screen with the service' WSDL (assuming they have mex turned on). Try that and see what you get. If you get nothing, you may have a network or firewall issue.

Comment: @Legart, I added contract and config.

Comment: Could you please also share client code for connecting to the service.  And share Uri you use on client side to connect to the service.

Answer (score 0):

There is no baseaddress in you config file:

```
<services>
  <service name="TnT.Services.TnTService">
    <endpoint address="basic1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TnT.Services.ITnTService"/>

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1295"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```